# How to onclick check password (form) and if correct show hidden div on same page without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, passwords

I've been trying to have a password only form that shows a hidden div on the same page as the form when the password is correct.
I don't want to reload either but not sure how to do that.

```js
function checkPswd() {
  var confirmpassword = "admin";
  var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (password == confirmpassword) {
    document.getElementById('hidden');
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      alert('tryagain');
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  };}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <label for="pswd">enter password</label>
  <input type="password" id="pass">
  <input type="button" value="go" onsubmit="checkPswd();" /></form>
<div class="hidden">
  <p>this part I want hidden from people who don't know the password</p>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure the javascript is wrong but is there another way to do this?

Comment: An `<input>` does not dispatch a `submit` event. Inline event handlers like `onsubmit` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: You never use `document.getElementById('hidden')` and you never define `x`. Checking CSS properties directly is [best avoided](/q/55071684/4642212). Instead, simply use [`.classList.contains("hidden")`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check for its existence, and, in your case, directly `.classList.toggle("hidden")`, etc. Consider using the [`hidden` attribute](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => { event.preventDefault(); /* The password check here. When ready to submit: */ event.target.submit(); });`. Consider using [`requestSubmit`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit).

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

1. You forgot to assign the returned value of `document.getElementById('hidden')` to `x`
2. A button does not have a `submit` event. You are perhaps looking for the `click` event
3. There is no element with the `hidden` id. You are mixing it up with the element with the `hidden` class.

```js
function checkPswd() {
  var confirmpassword = "admin";
  var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (password == confirmpassword) {
    var x = document.querySelector('.hidden');
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      alert('tryagain');
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <label for="pswd">enter password</label>
  <input type="password" id="pass">
  <input type="button" value="go" onclick="checkPswd();" /></form>
<div class="hidden">
  <p>this part I want hidden from people who don't know the password</p>
</div>
```